# Android 4.4 OTA system update hangs on Nexus 7 (2013)

Tags: updates, ota-update

I got a Nexus 7 (2013) with Android 4.3. Some time ago the system reported that system update to 4.4 is available, but I did not install it because I use the device for developement and wanted to finish development cycle under 4.3. All this time notification bar was displaying an icon for the update. As far as I can remember the message was that the update is downloaded and ready to install.

Today I noticed that the icon disappeared. I opened system settings and then `About tablet` ->  `System updates`. On the screen there is the message:

```
Android 4.4.2
System Update
Downloading 253.2MB
Via Wi-Fi only until Dec 14
```

The problem is that the progress indicator is frozen at something about 10%.

The questions are:

- Does someone know if the 4.4.2 is a cumulative update including initial 4.4 release, and if it's not - how can I "tell" the system to install 4.4 first?
- How can I nudge the downloading and installation process? I already switched the device off and on, and this did not help. I'd prefer to make the update via Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved. AFAICU, there was possibly a problem with Android update hosting site or somewhere on a trace to it, because the device was connected to and was capable of browsing Internet without a problem, including google.com. After some time, even without updating the progress indicator, the device displayed `Install & Reboot` button. After this all goes well. So, the answers are:

- Android provides cumulative update to 4.4.2, at least for Nexus 7 (2013).
- Android should improve the way how it shows status information. If it encounters some problems with downloading an update, it should output something like "Connection timeout, trying to reconnect..." instead of just "Downloading" all the time. Also the progress indicator may have a bug preventing it from proper UI update in similar sitations.